# Adiabatic expansion of the universe

Tags: thermodynamics, cosmology, space-expansion, adiabatic

I was wondering why we consider the universe to expand adiabatically. If the universe is a closed system shouldn't be the energy conserved? Does the adiabatic expansion change the total internal energy?

Comment: The expansion is adiabatic *because* the universe is closed and has constant internal energy.

Comment: @AndersSandberg I'm not so sure it is known whether the universe is indeed an *isolated* system. And the universe lacks time translational symmetry, so the internal energy shouldn't be constant.

Comment: @electronpusher - The isolated part seems to be almost definitional for universes. But the time translation issue is correct, and I was wrong in my comment.